# Flutter get multiple request in ListView

Tags: flutter

In flutter i have a simple `ListView` which that contains some data into that, for example you suppose i have 5 row in it,

now for each row in `ListView` i want to send request to the server to get response, you suppose again each row into this list is `Instagram` pages posts, and i want to get like count from server for each row in the list. or like with `Telegram` as you maybe know when we scroll posts, we can see posts seen.

could you help me how can i implementing this feature in `Flutter`? sending request from each row in the list

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a tutorial community. What have you tried so far and what is not working?

Comment: @DimitriL. i know that, i'll to know whats solution about that, please read my post again carefullym thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you would have more than a fixed number of 5 rows, the `ListView.builder` constructor is what you want:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) async {
    final response = await http.get('https://anyurl/getData/contentId/${index}');

    final parsedResponse = parseResponse(response);

    return ListTile(
      title: Text('${parsedResponse.title}'),
    );
  },
);
```

The ListView builder gives you the index of the list item currently being built and lets you create any widgets that are displayed as elements.

*`parseResponse` is a dummy function, which of course does not exist, because it has to be implemented by yourself.*

Answer (score 1):

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) async {
    var itemPosition = index+1;
    final response = await http.get('https://anyurl/getData/contentId/$itemPosition');
    final item = parseResponse(response);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('${item.name'), \\name is your fetched JSON
    );
  },
);
```

[image]